# Como ordenar el contenido dentro de un archivo

Tags: c++, dev-c++

Mi duda bueno consiste en como poder generar una función dentro de este parámetro que me pueda ordenar las palabra del archivo creado  a raíz del original el cual se pide ordenar.

```
void abrirarchivo(char ink[] , char outk[]){
    ifstream p1;
    ofstream p2;
    char texto;
    cout << "Ingrese el archivo original " << endl; //Archivo el cual tiene que ser ordenado
    cin.getline(ink , size); 
    p1.open(ink);

    if(!x1){
        cout << "Error " << p2 << endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE ) ;
    }

    cout << "Ingrese un nombre para el nuevo archivo ordenado " ; 
    cin.getline(outk , size );

    p2.open(outk);

    if(!p2){
        cout << "Error " << outk << endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}
```

Comment: Las funciones no se generan dentro de parámetros. ¿Cuál es el parámetro al que te refieres con "*este parametro*"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes ordenar automáticamente las palabras si las almacenas en un [`std::multiset`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multiset):

> `std::multiset` es un contenedor asociativo que contiene una colección de objetos ordenados de tipo `Key`. A diferencia del `set`, se permiten múltiples elementos con valores equivalentes.

Así que, el siguiente código:

```
std::multiset<std::string> palabras;

palabras.insert("Zanzibar");
palabras.insert("albaricoque");
palabras.insert("Multidisciplinar");
palabras.insert("abutarda");
palabras.insert("Concupiscencia");

for (const auto &palabra : palabras)
    std::cout << palabra << '\n';
```

Genera la siguiente salida:

> ```
> Concupiscencia
> Multidisciplinar
> Zanzibar
> abutarda
> albaricoque
> ```

Observarás que las palabras que empiezan en mayúsculas se ordenan antes que las que empiezan en minúsculas, esto sucede porque las letras mayúsculas tienen un valor ASCII menor a las minúsculas:

[image]

Para evitar este problema, puedes personalizar el contenedor con un comparador personalizado:

```
auto compara = [lower = [](char c){ return std::tolower(c); }](std::string a, std::string b)
{
    std::transform(a.begin(), a.end(), a.begin(), lower);
    std::transform(b.begin(), b.end(), b.begin(), lower);
    return a < b;
};
std::multiset<std::string, decltype(compara)> palabras(compara);

palabras.insert("Zanzibar");
palabras.insert("albaricoque");
palabras.insert("Multidisciplinar");
palabras.insert("abutarda");
palabras.insert("Concupiscencia");

for (const auto &palabra : palabras)
    std::cout << palabra << '\n';
```

Ahora la salida es  la siguiente:

> ```
> abutarda
> albaricoque
> Concupiscencia
> Multidisciplinar
> Zanzibar
> ```

Si además del `std::multiset` reescribimos tu código siguiendo las recomendaciones de C++ moderno, podría parecerse a:

```
void abrirarchivo(){
    string nombre_archivo;
    cout << "Ingrese el archivo original " << endl; // Archivo el cual tiene que ser ordenado
    cin >> nombre_archivo;

    auto compara = [lower = [](char c){ return std::tolower(c); }](std::string a, std::string b)
    {
        std::transform(a.begin(), a.end(), a.begin(), lower);
        std::transform(b.begin(), b.end(), b.begin(), lower);
        return a < b;
    };
    std::multiset<std::string, decltype(compara)> palabras(compara);

    if (std::ifstream archivo{nombre_archivo})
    {
        std::string linea;
        while (std::getline(archivo, linea))
            palabras.insert(linea);
    }
    else
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    cout << "Ingrese un nombre para el nuevo archivo ordenado " ; 
    cin >> nombre_archivo;

    if (std::ofstream archivo{nombre_archivo})
    {
        for (const auto &palabra : palabras)
            archivo << palabra << '\n';
    }
    else
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVTbitswEH22vmJwoWtDmu1zkgaWsoVA@1JaKO0uy1ieOAJZcmV5d1uTb0/HtpxLk17epJk5mjNnji2r6pXUaIrd7oUyUjc5wULZ2jvCcikOsfV5iCPKFCcR8sdX1IV1ym9OUFL6HxUthXi0KgfMnHLo5EY92iRtRdTU/CYYLKmuUBLUPp8LEQ29wNgyc/QQAHMRSdt4WCwgXpnCUU1AGkIWuHehDGqIuwoyuZ7D9TXchDRXyoazXpEh@N5wL3IMyslgbvlpZWC5PGspImy8BWnLCh3CG/im7RMD@XCfyA06kGkLjnzjTMd@NvO2r0hkOoftfdLHwjw4geNrloqINYgGmENTr60rE5xmxJMk6QRwynMMh32sfz2dn@OyQ0024rJLuMAWYQEZ37dzMTxVNtorXuriiOQEcpK622ESNEiXUKHmTWK9D3U6qTUMw6pgnnEz7amm2@OpgxJaGcKO2tNGaQrvFOS7eBJwk6EqZXgUjQymyvAafTKkumFERLomrqFn5ZPbL6tPD@9uVu8/f7ztWZ45qDFh59AvmG1iGmK/HGw1OOTYVn9xy14F@38q8OaAZTS1h95oL8NkMNur3A880mEOYwUfr@7M1T@H3gqhjIcSOx@I9hJH28Z26p993NGK@i7xW2tkU6lakpEK70zc0Yg/dB7JOaoq1hzdGP@K5qfKDnfMGo8u3@NQc1JJyx8eh5jz6a/gsoFUG9d7Wr97JsjwJ9eoyVgxOKZPjtu/JKEYv4vXLNlu1@sh@vbiFw)</kbd>.